# Anchor link not working with .slideUp jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Can you help me why my anchor link not work.**

I have 3 anchor links 
eg:
Google (not work)
Yahoo (not work)
Facebook (work)

Why google and yahoo not work?

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Socail Media</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**MY CODE HERE JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/smithfoto/mfrp9ueh/)

Comment: remove `return false;`. http://jsfiddle.net/mfrp9ueh/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the

```
return false;
```

from your code.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mfrp9ueh/4/)